# Saved image only shows rectangle created using cv2.rectangle and not the whole image on which rectangle was created

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

When Using this code:

```
 start_point = (centerXList[i] +16,centerYList[i]-14)
 end_point = (centerXList[i]+50,centerYList[i]+24)
 color=(255,0,0)
 x1=cv2.rectangle(x1,start_point,end_point,color)
 imshow(x1)
 plt.show()
```

The results of imshow are:

[image]

But when saving the image using:

`save_img("./Predicted Images/abc.jpeg", x1)`

The result is:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A4q1buJJk9tBWfstQccgETHe8LDEOtxX/view?usp=sharing

I want to save the image the same as displayed by imshow.
How to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The code you have shared works as it should be. The problem is, an image is previously added in your `plt`. To show the image as well, append the image before using `plt.imshow(img)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my problem was:

```
save_img("./Predicted Images/abc.jpeg", x1 * 255)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryied saving the photo by using this:

```
cv2.imwrite('my_saved_image', img)
```

Comment: I tried it
It didn't work